# $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral with $\angle CAB=60^\circ$, $\angle CAD=20^\circ$, $\angle ABD=50^\circ$, $\angle DBC=10^\circ$. Find $\angle ACD$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

Can you help me solve this Olympiad angles problem?

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral such that: $\widehat{CAB}=60^\circ$; $\widehat{CAD}=20^\circ$; $\widehat{ABD}=50^\circ$; $\widehat{DBC}=10^\circ$.
>
> Calculate $\widehat{ACD}$.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I've got $20^\circ$, what about you?

Comment: i found 80° @MichaelHoppe

Comment: You're right, as $AD=AC$. I was a bit too fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be the intersection point of lines $AC$ and $BD$.

Then:

$\angle BEC=60^\circ+50^\circ=110^\circ$

$\begin{align} \angle BCE&= 180^\circ-110^\circ - 10^\circ \\ &=60^\circ \\ &= \angle{BAC} \end{align}$

So that means $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral and hence:

$AB=AC \tag 1$

You can also deduce that:

$\begin{align} \angle BDA &= 180^\circ - 60^\circ - 20^\circ - 50^\circ \\ &= 50^\circ \\ &= \angle ABD \end{align}$

So $\Delta BAD$ is isosceles and hence:

$AB=AD \tag 2$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ leads to:

$AD=AC$

Meaning that:

> $\triangle DAC$ is isosceles

I believe you can finish up now.

Comment: Thank you so much @QuangHoang , i've got 80°

Comment: @Rfgauss to be clear, it’s not my answer.